# Subscript in macro

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

I would like to define a new command like the following.
The latex when compiling should emit `I_{wr}` when given without arguments, or the optional arguments should come as a subscript.

```
\newcommand{\myCommand}[1][]{I_{wr#1}}
```

So If I give `$\myCommand{2}$`, then it would emit the text as `I_{wr}2`. The `2` does not come in the subscript form. Could anyone please tell me how to do this correctly?

Thank You

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's already correct except for the usage:

```
\newcommand{\myCommand}[1][]{I_{wr#1}}
```

The argument is an *optional* argument that uses *square* brackets:

```
$\myCommand[2]$
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\myCommand}[1][]{I_{wr#1}}

\begin{document}
\[
  \myCommand[2] = 2 * \myCommand
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]